# Creating Folders using walk and purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to create a little function that will set up a work environment in R
In the end it will just be a function where i can specify the folder structure i want to set up
I would like to take this as a chance to learn `purrr`

Below is my code which has been setup in a project so the file path is inherent but i am clearly not using it correctly

```
# Setup Project Folders
library('purrr')
my_folders <- data.frame(folder = c('scripts','sql','figs','results','data','ref_data','reports'))
walk(.f = dir.create(file.path(), showWarnings = FALSE),.x =my_folders)
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `dir.create` is not vectorized, however, `walk` on your data frame will pass a 1-column data frame to `dir.create` which will cause the error you see.

My approach here would be to use `by_row` to make sure that you have elements of length 1 passed to `dir.create`, and force the coercion to a character vector:

```
my_folders %>%
  by_row(function(x) dir.create(as.character(x),
         showWarnings = FALSE), .collate = "rows",
         .to = "success")
```

This will only work if your data frame has a single column. To make it safer:

```
my_folders %>%
  by_row(function(x) dir.create(as.character(x$folder),
         showWarnings = FALSE), .collate = "rows",
         .to = "success")
```

I'm pretty new to purrr so there might be a better way...